# React cannot find module, '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object' (0:undefined) on Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, npm, babeljs, craco

Jenkins Error noted on the console.log terminal

```
13:29:56  Syntax error: [BABEL] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object' (0:undefined)
13:29:56  Require stack:
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-babel/dist/index.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/cra.js
13:29:56  - /var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/scripts/build.js (While processing: "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/govt-finance/qa/build-and-deploy-web/node-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/prod.js")
```

package.json File

```
{
  "name": "govt-finance-ui",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "credit-card-type": "^10.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^3.0.6",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-csv-downloader": "^3.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.25.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropdown-select": "^4.11.1",
    "react-form-validator-core": "^1.1.2",
    "react-payment-inputs": "^1.1.9",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^6.4.2",
    "react-router": "^6.21.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "use-csv-downloader": "0.0.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8000 craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco --openssl-legacy-provider test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off",
      "no-mixed-operators": "off",
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.1"
  }
}
```

craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
        require('postcss-nested'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    }
  },

  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          // path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
          crypto: require.resolve("./src/crypto-browserify"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
          vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify")
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Fails when running "npm run build" command after it's pushed to Jenkins server but works locally (Gives no errors or warnings locally when built)

Jenkins pipeline (Build section)

```
stage('build') {
    steps {
        timestamps {
            timeout(time: 4000, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                dir('node-app') {
                    
                    withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: '******', url: 'https://**********'){ 

                        sh """#!/bin/bash
                        set -e
                        source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
                        
                        nvm list
                        nvm install 20.7.0
                        nvm use 20.7.0
                        node --version

                        npm install

                        npm run build
                        docker build --build-arg REACT_APP_API_HOST --build-arg REACT_APP_API_KEY --build-arg REACT_APP_ENC_KEY --build-arg REACT_APP_SANDDOLLAR_PYMT -t $APP_REGISTRY:${env.BUILD_TAG}  -t $APP_REGISTRY:latest .
                        docker push  $APP_REGISTRY:${env.BUILD_TAG}
                        docker push  $APP_REGISTRY:latest
                        """
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried removing the node_modules folder, package-lock.json file, reinstalling all packages after removal...

As seen in the package.json file I dev save installed the "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", and "@babel/preset-env" packages.

I had an issue like this with a previous project but adding those solved the problem.

The only difference I notice with the error is that on the end of the line there is " (0:undefined)" on the first line of the error mentioned in the Jenkins console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it the build successfully by removing **"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"**, and **"@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.1"** from the devDependencies and placing them into main Dependencies list

Added below code into craco.config.js

```
  babel: {
presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
plugins: [
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
]
```

},

And then added the following into Jenkins Pipeline

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm install
npm run build
```

**Now I am getting a process is undefined error from _stream_writable.js:57**

But at least the program runs/builds successfully now

**Update:** fixed process error by following this guide:

[Using crypto NodeJS module in React-Native (step-by-step)](https://gist.github.com/pedrouid/629367f8d1b69bf1f93992b2be87bab1)